# Streaming video from Unity's camera target texture to RTSP

Tags: unity-game-engine, ffmpeg, video-streaming, rtsp

I've been trying to find ways of streaming video from Unity's camera to an RTSP stream.

So far I've been trying out this particular plugin here https://github.com/keijiro/FFmpegOut which takes the camera's target texture as the input, and outputs it as an MP4 file on the disk, and https://github.com/aler9/rtsp-simple-server as a simple RTSP server

My initial thought was that it'd be as easy as changing the original FFMPEG commandline syntax from this:

```
  "-y -f rawvideo -vcodec rawvideo -pixel_format rgba"
+ " -colorspace bt709"
+ " -video_size 800x600"
+ " -framerate 30"
+ " -pix_fmt yuv420p"
+ " test.mp4"
```

to this:

```
  "-y -re -f rawvideo -vcodec rawvideo -pixel_format rgba"
+ " -colorspace bt709"
+ " -video_size 800x600"
+ " -framerate 30"
+ " -pix_fmt yuv420p"
+ " -f rtsp -rtsp_transport tcp rtsp://127.0.0.1:8554/stream"
```

This works for the first 4-5 seconds of streaming which I can view on VLC player. But after that, the process just hangs and I'll have to terminate it, with the same behaviour regardless of it being run through the Unity Editor, or as a standalone.

Would greatly appreciate any help with this, or thoughts on how I should pinpoint which part of the chain might be breaking down, or even alternative plugins/resources I can look into in order to achieve this. Thanks!

Edit: Also looked through the Unity Player and Editor logs, but there weren't any error messages.

Comment: I -might- have figured it out actually, after reading through this question posted here
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7025060/ffmpeg-exe-freezes
The plugin has coded the process to only handle redirected standard errors AFTER the application is stopped, which could be causing it to freeze. After setting ProcessStartInfo.RedirectStandardError to false, it seems to be streaming perfectly fine. But well, could still be a red herring until I do more rigorous tests...